# writing react components in a functional style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks

I'm learning react and elm at the same time and the similarities made me wonder if I could write all of my react components like in the snippet bellow instead of using classes

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("oof")

  return (
    <div className="App App-header">
      <Head/>
      <Adorable name={name}/>
      <AdoreForm setName={setName}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const Head = () =>
  <header>Adorable Genator OwO</header>

const Adorable = (props) =>
  <img src={`https://api.adorable.io/avatars/221/${props.name}@adorable.png`}/>

const AdoreForm = (props) =>
  <div>
    <input onChange={(e) => props.setName(e.target.value)}/>
  </div>
```

Comment: _"The simplest way to define a component is to write a JavaScript function."_ [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). You can write your components like this, but I'd evaluate beforehand --> does it make sense, are those components extendable ("future-proof") or are meant to stay simple. Is your code more manageable understandable through this.

Comment: I wonder how only writing functional components would scale

Comment: jep, with the introduction of react hooks, the functional is even the preferred way...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write your code as you have shown in the snippet. You can also use arrow functions to create your app component as follows.

```
 const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("oof")

  return (
    <div className="App App-header">
      <Head/>
      <Adorable name={name}/>
      <AdoreForm setName={setName}/>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

It doesn't matter what sort of method (i.e : class or functional) you are using to create components especially with the introduction of react hooks.

Comment: except that hooks don't work with class based components